# Mantener chromedriver funcionando despues de una actualizacion

Tags: selenium, chromedriver

Tengo una aplicacion en Java que usa selenium y `chromedriver`.
Este ultimo depende a su vez de `google-chrome` para su funcionamiento.
En cierto punto, una actualizacion manual/automatica de `google-chrome` o `chromedriver` lleva al siguiente mensaje:

> *This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version XX*

Y la solucion temporal es ya sea actualizar `chromedriver` o `google-chrome` para mantener iguales versiones.

Mi pregunta es: Que solucion a largo plazo se puede entregar para que el chromedriver no se vuelva obsoleto y se actualice a la version de google-chrome actual?

He intentado una serie de scripts para actualizar el chromedriver localmente usando el ultimo RELEASE (que deberia estar alineado en version con la ultima version de chrome instalada):

```
# script para macos
VERSION=$(curl https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE)
curl -o chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$VERSION/chromedriver_mac64.zip
unzip -o chromedriver.zip && rm chromedriver.zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un problema muy comun, y era un quebradero de cabeza siempre. Pero desde que descubri la libreria [webdrivermanager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) no he tenido que volver a preocuparme de eso. Ha sido todo un descubrimiento.

Es una libreria que se encarga ella sola de actualizar el binario de los navegadores que utilizas con selenium. En tu caso actualiza automaticamente tu chromedriver para que no quede obsoleto. Ademas puedes usarla para ejecuciones con versiones anteriores a la ultima.

Comment: Gracias por la información, me imaginaba que alguien ya habia implementado alguna solucion, pero mejor aun enlazada con el projecto usando maven. Estaba a punto de implementar algo pero no queria complicar el desarrollo.